# How to get WindowManager in a Service?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to convert a Java example that I found for Android to C#:

```cs
[Service]
public class SampleService :Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        // create a windowManager object - relatively easy
        var windowManager = GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

        // create layoutParams based on WindowManager LayoutParams class 
        // (i.e. static member of class that doesn't exist in service context?!?!
        var layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the C# world `WindowManager` doesn't seem to be available in a Service, whereas in Java it is (at least according to the example that I saw.

In C# `IWindowManager` is available but that doesn't contain the static members.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that instead of using the `WindowManager`, I can use the class

```
WindowManagerLayoutParams
```

So the code:

```
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
```

becomes

```
var layoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(1, 1, 
    WindowManagerTypes.SystemOverlay, 
    WindowManagerFlags.WatchOutsideTouch, 
    Format.Translucent);
```

Comment: It seems, that I try something very similar. Did you get it to work? 
Could you show the complete converted sample? My problem is that I run into a NotSupportedException when trying to Add the view.